# Displaying multiple jQuery effects for multiple clicks on different elements with the same tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am writing a Rails app, and as part of its dynamic content, it will render multiple `<p>` elements containing text as part of the markdown.

In the end, I want to make it so that when clicking each of these `<p>` elements, I can toggle in some content on the right side of the blog post.

jQuery seems like a natural fit to do this, and adding this effect to one element when one `<p>` is clicked is pretty easy:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
            <p id="category"><%= post.category %></p>
            <div id="paragraph"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>    
    <% end %>
</div> 

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="exampleToggle">
        <p>This is my example content.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".exampleToggle" ).hide();

        $("p").click(function(){
            $(".exampleToggle").toggle();
            });
    });
</script>
```

**The Problem**: In the current form, it will let me add in `exampleToggle` when the first `<p>` is clicked, but clicking a 2nd `<p>` will then hide the element rather than generate a 2nd one. In short, I want to bring multiple `#exampleToggle` divs in if multiple paragraphs are clicked.

**Possible Solution:** From looking at documentation, a simple approach in some cases would be to use `getElementByID` and then label each paragraph with a different ID. Unfortunately, because this is dynamic Rails content, when the page renders, each block of text becomes its own `<p>` without the ability for me to tag each one as an ID. I will have to handle this dynamic content.

**Question:** Is it possible - based on this dynamic element aspect - to use jQuery to bring in multiple `#exampleToggle` divs: one for each time a paragraph is clicked?

Comment: You realize that `id` attributes are meant to be unique on any given page, right? You can get away with naming multiple elements with the same designation, but if you use `getElementById`, you're always going to get a reference to the first element of that name -- the others will be ignored. Have you tried using class names? `class = exampleToggle` and in your JS `$(".exampleToggle").hide();`

Comment: Good point, mistake when I was mocking this up to a show an example. I now have changed everything to be a `(".exampleToggle"). While necessary though, I think the underlying issue is still there when I run this: clicking the `<p>` element toggles in and/or hides only one element of the `exampleToggle` class.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't hold out much hope of resolving this with my observations. Just trying to get you a little bit closer. I don't personally know whether JQuery can do what you want because I've only used `.toggle()` on entire`<div>` elements.